1990s(?) fantasy book with a female mage protagonist and demons
I am trying to remember the name of a fantasy novel I read in the 90s, which I think was published then too.
It centers around a young (rare) female mage who is very lonely. She has just graduated from mage school. She enters the service of some sort of noble.
There are demons who can enter their world, and I think it happens when a mage is undisciplined in using their power— related to that, a female mage’s “purity” is supposedly the root of their power.
In any event, she is befriended by a handsome lord at court. She begins to fall in love with him and it turns out he is a demon, and far from being weak, she is one of the most powerful mages to have ever lived— and her mentor (master?) was using her power for himself. She is able to defeat the demon on her own, but at significant psychological trauma.
There are descriptions of her smelling rotting roses, which we learn occurs when a demon has been present.
There were a few books in the series and I can’t for the life of me remember more detail.

Is this Mage Heart (1996) by Jane Routley...? It's the first book in the The Chronicles of Dion trilogy.

An Amazon review notes that the protagonist, Dion Holyhands, is trained to be a mage by a man named Michael, who bought her from her mother. After Michael dies, Dion is summoned from a school of magic by a duke to protect his favourite mistress, Kitten Avignon, from a necromancer. Dion somehow calls a demon to her who'll do anything to cross over into her world. Furthermore, she meets a mesmerising lord named Andre Gregorov, who claims to be in love with her but whose true identity and motives are in doubt.

Dion was just an ordinary young girl when she came to the attention of Michael, a great mage. Michael bought her from her mother to see if it was possible to train a female to be a mage. Michael completely takes over Dion's life as she has no other friends or teachers. When Dion is older, she cannot really remember a life before Michael. She knows that she has often been a disappointment to him and fears what will become of her now that Michael is dead. There is no place for a female mage in Gallia and Dion doesn't really have any training as a healer, the only acceptable role for a female with magicial powers. So it is a relief to the Dean of the School of Magic when the Duke calls on her to protect his favorite mistress, Kitten Avignon, from a necromancer with a grudge.
Dion tries to refuse, terrified that she will lose all that is left to her now - her unsullied reputation. After all, how can she be seen to consort with the women of the "honey sisterhood" and not be thought a courtesan herself? However, when the necromancer sends an assassin into the College of Magics to kill Dion, she has no choice but to move in with Kitten and accept the physical protection that that will provide her. Dion is ill prepared for the world of political intrigue in which she finds herself and struggles to fit Kitten's view of the world and Michael's view together. But Dion has a bigger problem, she has somehow called a Demon to her and the Demon will do anything to cross over into Dion's world where innocent prey abounds. Dion both fears and desires the demon's power, but she knows that to use demon magic is the worst kind of necromancy. Matters are further complicated when she meets the mesmerizing Andre Gregorov, a sophisticated foreigner who claims to be passionately in love with her. But who is he really and why does he want her? Dion soon discovers that nothing and no one is what it appears. Can she have the confidence in herself to make the right choices and to use her great magical gift to protect those most important to her?

The following extract from the Google Books preview of the book itself describes Dion experiencing a drug-induced vision in which she encounters a demon and smells a scent like rotting roses.

The rock was so close; my desire was a torment. Recklessly I stepped into the sea and began to wade. It was not cold and wet as I'd expected, but warm and vicious, like jelly. It held me up, smoothly and firmly. The little gaping maws seemed to move aside for me. As I got deeper in, I boticed little pink tongues lashing out of them as I passed. It tickled deliciously where they touched the skin. There was a sickly scent, rotting and sweet, like nothing I had ever smelled. So strong that it was nauseating. Like roses-postulant, rotting roses.
By the time I had waded in up to my waist, I knew that the being on the rock was, as I'd prayed, indeed a demon. It crouched there, betoothed and beclawed, its scaly wings spread out as if to dry, its face to the swirling stars.

And this extract from the book notes that Michael taught her that she must retain her purity at all costs, since magic is best pursued by celibates.

These were not thoughts for a mage. Nor were the thoughts that sometimes came to me early in the soft grey mornings. I would wake up with my own hand cupped around my breast or feeling the smoothness of the sheets against my bare legs and lie there in sleepy sensuality, dreaming that someone lay there with me and held me and loved me. In those moments I was as full of love as a ripe fruit is full of juice, and the thought that I should never have anyone to give all this love to filled me with vague melancholy. I could not imagine ever attracting anyone. Anyway, Michael had always told me that I must at all costs retain my purity. Magic was best pursued by celibates.

